# Random Background image through external CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have to change background image of class randomly using external CSS file.
Image has to pick randomly from define path.

I know how to handle this in php, i have to implement it in external css file.

looking for any css trick.

here is css class properties.

```
.birthday
 {
   background:url(../images/Bday.jpg) no-repeat center;
   font: bold 25px "trebuchet ms", Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: #930204;
   padding: 25px 0px 0px 200px;
   height: 195px;
 }
```

path is given as per file structure.

Comment: may you should take a look at **[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)**

Comment: Sorry Mr.Alien, i didn't get u. Plz explain

Comment: I like the idea of @Mr.Alien. But If you don't know all the images that you want to cycle, you could also use a dynamic target as background-image. like `background:url(../images/getimage.php)`. I have not tryed that before but it should work. It's more work than the plain CSS solution.

Comment: how to manage @keyframe on page reload.

Comment: @NicoO I like your solution best; maybe you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using `pure CSS`.

Also  You can use javascript to random and set the background image of your website.

see this tutorial..

[Randomize background image](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/)

[Impossibly simple image randomize with jQuery](http://briancray.com/posts/simple-image-randomizer-jquery/)

or

**Try this method**

At first create an array of images

```
var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg'];
```

Now, set a random image as the background image:

```
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() *      images.length)] + ')'});
```

I hope this code will help for You,
Thanks..

Comment: Its helpful for me. But I was looking for pure css solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47430/discussion-between-kesavan-and-shri)